# How to ground private 2/0 aerial triplex from meter to garage

Tags: electrical, wiring, grounding

Where to ground aerial 2/0 triplex bare neutral at the meter/pole. Can I connect directly to power company strand/neutral? Or connect to mast (customer equipment)?

Comment: "to power company strand" implies that YOU should not be doing anything with it. Call the power company and let them connect it. The fact that you bought the wire does not give you some sort of pass on having them connect it to their equipment...

Comment: Thanks... simple enough.

Comment: Yeah, ***you*** usually need safety ground to be carried separate from neutral.  The ***power company*** does not bring need to bring ground.  The problem comes up when you ask the PoCo to wire a feeder for you; they just go "hey, we'll just use *our stuff* that doesn't supply ground; we don't care about NEC!"  The PoCo doesn't even have quadplex on the truck, because very few 3-phase installations come in on a pole line.

Comment: So the PoCo put a triplex in on your behalf for power to the garage? Does turning off the main breaker at the pole turn the garage off or not?

Answer (score 2):

Sadly, with this type of feeder, you are obliged to use the bare wire as a safety ground (unless you can get a waiver from your local authority to treat it as a service).

That gives you two options: run 120V-only, or run 240V-only and use a transformer to derive 120/240V service.   This might be sensible if the lion's share of your load is 240V only and your 120V loads comprise only receptacles abd lights.